# Neutron scattering off molecules

Tags: scattering, molecules, neutrons

From neutron scattering off molecules it is possible to get information about molecules' geometry. Given the size of a particular molecule, what are the criteria for choosing the wavelengh of the incident slow neutrons?  Should also the interatomic distances of atoms within the molecule considered? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't observe neutron scattering from a single molecule.  However if you have many molecules organized coherently in space --- that is, a crystal --- you can use the standard techniques of neutron scattering to determine the structure of each component cell of the crystal, which includes the structure of the underlying molecule.

A very popular technique is to contrast x-ray diffraction patterns to neutron diffraction patterns for the same substance.  X-rays and thermal/cold neutrons have approximately the same wavelength.  X-rays, however, interact mostly with electrons and therefore mostly ignore hydrogen; neutrons have a particularly large scattering cross section from hydrogen.  Comparisons of the two techniques thus does a great job of locating the hydrogen atoms in a complicated crystal.

Protein crystallography is a major part of the research effort at places like LANSCE and the SNS.

To address your question about choosing a neutron wavelength in a general way, you get the most information from diffraction patterns when the wavelength of the diffracting particle is comparable to the distance between scatterers.